# How to get pd.Grouper() to include empty groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that I want to groupby a column AND every month of data in the dataset. I'm using `pd.Grouper()` for the groupby date per month part of it.

```
df.groupby(['A',pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')]).agg({'B':list})
```

But this returns only the months for each `A`,`B` that actually have data. I also want every month where there was no data for that `A`,`B` combo. I don't see this option in the `pd.Grouper()` documentation.

Comment: grouper won't return data that is not there, you need to produce the actual pair (Month, NaN)

Comment: @Yuca so I have to impute my data before hand with every combination of month and `A` with empty set for `B`?

Comment: well, without sample data it's hard to answer you, but yeah, you need to. There might be smart ways to go about it

Comment: Do you need empty lists just over the range within each group, or is the range the same across all groups? (i.e. if A has data from 2017 only, but B has data from 2016-2017, should A be resampled over 2016-2017 or just 2017?).

Comment: @ALollz the range is the same across all groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this DataFrame:

```
date        A  B
2018-01-01  1  3
2018-03-01  2  4
```

After the groupby you can use resample BUT in order to resample [unfortunately](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16267) you need to create the MultiIndex yourself:

```
In [11]: res = df.groupby(['A',pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')]).agg({'B':list})

In [12]: m = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.A.unique(), pd.date_range(df.date.min(), df.date.max() + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1), freq='M')])

In [13]: m
Out[13]:
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2], [2018-01-31 00:00:00, 2018-02-28 00:00:00, 2018-03-31 00:00:00]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])

In [14]: res.reindex(m)
Out[14]:
                B
1 2018-01-31  [3]
  2018-02-28  NaN
  2018-03-31  NaN
2 2018-01-31  NaN
  2018-02-28  NaN
  2018-03-31  [4]
```

Note: to fillna with [] is a little tricky, ideally you'd be able to work around this (in general having lists inside a DataFrame is not recommended).

Comment: Thanks for the note. That's a good point. Maybe I will break out the list into multiple rows and have a unique row for each value in the list.